# isset submit is not working

Tags: php

I am using `isset` function to check if the submit button is clicked, but it's not working. It is not entering into the `if`. here is my code. I am not getting where the problem persists.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td><h2><br />
            User Registration</h2>
            <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="return Validate();">
                User Name[E-mail ID]: <input type="text" name="username" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
                Password : <input type="password" name="password" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
                Name <input type="text" name="name" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
                Contact Number: <input type="text" name="phone" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
                Email: <input type="text" name="email" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="REGISTER" />
            </form>

            <?php
            include('connect.php');
            if (isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                echo "1";
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                echo $username;

                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $phone = $_POST['phone'];   

                $email = $_POST['email'];
                //$id = $_GET['aid'];

                $sql = "INSERT INTO user_info(application_id, username, password, name, contact, email) VALUES (" . $aid. ", " .$username.", ".$password.", ".$name.",". $phone.", ".$email.") ";
                echo $sql;
                mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                //header("Location: index1.php");
            }

            ?>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: I think your HTML is wrong (you have not provided a name attribute for the submit field element). You need something like this: `<input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Click!" />` and in PHP, you need to invoke `isset($_POST['mysubmit'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<input type="submit" value="REGISTER" />
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="REGISTER" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all the replies. Just because of my silly mistake i missed the name filed. Sorry for taking your precious time. But thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the name attribute to your submit button

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="REGISTER" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an input element with a name of `submit`.

You could give your submit button this name, e.g.

```
<input type="submit" value="REGISTER" name="submit" />
```

or you can create a hidden input with the name instead:

```
<input type="hidden"  name="submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instead test if a form has been posted back with:

```
if (count($_POST) > 0)
{
    //code
}
```

This should only fire if there is at least one field that has been posted back.